# How to extend a sass/compass library

Tags: css, node.js, sass, gruntjs, compass-sass

My main goal is to add to this compass built-in mixin `sprite-position`:

```
@mixin sprite-position($col, $row: 1, $width: $sprite-image-default-width, $height: $sprite-image-default-height, $margin: $sprite-default-margin) {
  $x: ($col - 1) * -$width - ($col - 1) * $margin;
  $y: ($row - 1) * -$height - ($row - 1) * $margin;
  background-position: $x $y; 
}
```

and to add this retina mixin `sprite-position-retina`:

```
@mixin sprite-position-retina($col, $row: 1, $width: $sprite-image-default-width, $height: $sprite-image-default-height, $margin: $sprite-default-margin) {
  ...
  background-position: $x/2 $y/2; 
}
```

Eventually I want to replace this line of code in my file (this line is working):

```
    background-position: sprite-position($sprites2x, $name);
```

With this line (this line is not working):

```
    background-position: sprite-position-retina($sprites2x, $name);
```

The problem is that it doesn't even recognise `sprite-position-retina` ad a mixing and if I add `@include` to that line it doesn't recognise any of the variables and constants (as if the parameter I am passing are not the right ones)

**My questions are:**

1. Where should I add my new mixin? (Adding it to the built in file _sprite-img.scss seems like wrong practice because I don't want to change compass' inner files). Adding it to my files doesn't seem to make it work.
2. Why isn't it working? How can I make it work?

Project is built with grunt/bower/yo etc..

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice workaround for this problem:

I'm using this simple mixin to get the new sprite position:

```
/* Converts sprite position to half of its original size (since we're 'squizing' the retina image by 2)*/
@mixin sprite-position-retina($spriteUrl, $name) {
  $spriteData: sprite-position($spriteUrl, $name);
  $x: nth($spriteData,1)/2;
  $y: nth($spriteData,2)/2;
  background-position: $x $y;
}
```